# Overriding equals funct in ArraySet

Tags: android, set, android-support-library

How can i achieve this without getting

> error: cannot inherit from final ArraySet

```
ArraySet<MyObject>objectList = new ArraySet<MyObject>(){
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        return ((MyObject)this).getId()==((MyObject)object ).getId();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ArraySet`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/ArraySet.html) is a final class, meaning you can't inherit from it. You are trying to create an anonymous subclass when you write

```
ArraySet<MyObject>objectList = new ArraySet<MyObject>(){
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        return ((MyObject)this).getId()==((MyObject)object ).getId();
    }
};
```

What you really want to do is implement `equals` (and `hashcode`) for `MyObject`:

```
public class MyObject {
    ...
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof MyObject) {
            return getId() == ((MyObject) other).getId();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, the `ArraySet` will work as you intend

Comment: Thanks,  when i want to add a new item to the arrayset, how can i remove the one thats already and add the new duplicate? I want to update MyObject in that ArraySet.

Comment: @JuanPablo That's not the intention of a set. When using a set, duplicates are not stored, and most set implementations will keep the old value. One thing you could do is `objectSet.valueAt(myObjectIndex).myFunctionThatMutatesIt()` . Alternatively, you should use a different collection. Supposing that `getId()` returns an index starting at 0, you could just use an `ArrayList`. Alternatively, you should use a Map, such as [ArrayMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/ArrayMap.html): `ArrayMap<Integer, MyObject> objects = ...; objects.put(id, newMyObject);`

Comment: I think that should be a new question. Did you try using `remove()`? That said, with any set if you add an item and the item's `equals` match it will replace the old object

Comment: That's not really a valid thing to do, the item is already in the set.

Comment: I stand corrected, `Set` doesn't override the objects if the `equals` matches. I guess your best option is to `remove()` the old one first and then `add()` the new one

Comment: Thanks everyone. im going to use a new list to achieve what im trying to do.